# Issue using DataContext method

Tags: c#, asp.net, datacontext

I am trying to use the DataContext methods.
But when I type the following code ' private NorthWindDataContext Context' , it gives me an error saying that it could not be found in the namespace.
How do I use DataContext or what am I missing in this.

```
public partial class Northwind
{
    private NorthwindDataContext Context
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public Northwind()
    {
        Context = new NorthwindDataContext();
    }
```

Comment: what is the namespace you are using? how does the whole class look? how is the other partial class defined?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on `NorthWindDataContext` and select Resolve, It will get you the namespace (if you have). You can do the same thing with keyboard. Put your cursor on NorthWindDataContext and press Cntl+. (dot) and select the namespace to use